# Scala mutable.ListBuffer prepend/append not constant

Tags: scala, collections

I have a listbuffer with some predefined set of elements and I am unable to figure out the behaviour difference of using `:+`, `+:` and `+=`

Using `:+`

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.range(0,5000000)
    var i = 10
    while(i != 0) {
      println(measure {
        b = b.:+(1)
      })
      i = i - 1
    }
  }
}

63.273132 ms
1638.054828 ms
1341.641419 ms
53.644715 ms
474.193063 ms
63.242636 ms
330.665982 ms
79.725333 ms
290.109014 ms
55.515174 ms
```

Using `+:`

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.range(0,5000000)
    var i = 10
    while(i != 0) {
      println(measure {
        b = b.+:(1)
      })
      i = i - 1
    }
  }
}

72.501386 ms
1675.274467 ms
1380.867864 ms
52.565501 ms
383.728268 ms
51.046573 ms
314.941445 ms
53.824498 ms
270.233627 ms
52.864131 ms
```

Using `+=`

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var b = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.range(0,5000000)
    var i = 10
    while(i != 0) {
      println(measure {
        b = b+=1
      })
      i = i - 1
    }
  }
}

0.012685 ms
0.002234 ms
0.001569 ms
0.001383 ms
0.001398 ms
0.001499 ms
0.001413 ms
0.001416 ms
0.00147 ms
0.00136 ms
```

What's strange is `:+` and `+:` use `++=` eventually so why does it not act similarly? Benchmarking `++=` yields similar result as `+=`.

Am I missing something in the usage of ListBuffer? What's the difference between the three methods?

Comment: Why do you need a mutable reference of a mutable collection? Don't do that make it a `val` and use `+=` - Also, are you sure you are benchmarking the code correctly?` - Or use a `var` with an immutable `List`, use `::` to prepend and `reverse` at the end.

Comment: Yes we've switched to the += version now. But aside from the var vs val, what exactly is :+ and +: for?

Comment: To return copies instead of mutating the original object.